# What is wrong with the implementation of my queue as a list?

Tags: java, list, queue

I started with creating the variables `head` and `tail` of the queue, which are elements of a list themselves of course, and I create an empty list in the constructor by writing `head = tail = null`. In `enq`, I create a new element of the list called `help`, and it is supposed to save the new element that I want to put at the end of the list (since it is a queue). Of course the `tail` of the queue is always the element that we just put at the end of the list before. Then I check whether `head` is empty or not (either because the list itself is empty or because we deleted the first element of it, which should be always identical with `head`), and, if necessary, I define `head` as `help` too. Then `help` is supposed to show to a new empty element of the list.

The problem is the following: When I test my program, it stops after the very first delete and tells me that the list is already empty.

I guess the mistake lies within the method `deq`. I want to delete the first element by writing `head = head.next`, but we defined `head` as `help` before, thus, `head.next` is identical with `help.next`, which is identical with `null`, so the `boolean`-method returns that the list is empty, which stops the programm.

I might have to change the the "direction" of `help.next`, but I don't see how. How can make this whole thing work?

Creating the elements of the list:

```
public class Entry {
  Object content;
  Entry next;
}
```

Implementation of List:

```
public class QueueList implements List {

  private Entry head;
  private Entry tail;

  public QueueList() {
    head = tail = null;
  }

  public boolean empty() {
    return head == null;
  }

  public void enq(Object x) {
    Entry help = new Entry();
    help.content = x;
    tail = help;

    if (head == null) {
      head = help;
    }

    help.next = null;
  }

  public Object front() {
    return head.content;
  }

  public void deq() {
    head = head.next;
  }
}
```

Comment: Draw, on a piece of paper, what you're doing at each step of your enq method (for example), when calling it twice in a row. Do the same thing for the other methods.

Comment: You never set the `next` value of your `Entry` Objects to anything else but null. So of course `head = head.next;` will set your head to null. Just look at your code and look where you are modifying the `next` attribute.

Comment: My guess is that I simply overwrite `tail` each time I am calling the enq-method.

Comment: Don't guess. Draw your list on a piece of paper, at each step. An entry is a square box. A link to an entry to the next is an arrow. Another arrow for each variable, pointing at the entry that they refer to. Only write the arrows when the link is actually made in the code.

Comment: Will do so, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public void enq(Object x) {
    Entry help = new Entry();
    help.content = x;
    **tail = help;**

    if (head == null) {
      head = help;
    }

    help.next = null;
  }
```

There always will be only one element in the queue at any time.

This can be solved using the below enq() method

```
public void enq(Object x) {
        Entry help = new Entry(x);

        if (head == null) {

            head = help;

            tail = head;

        } else {
            if (head == tail) {

                head.next = help;
                tail = help;



            } else {

                this.tail.next = help;
                this.tail = help;
            }
        }

    }
```